# PHP find max between variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out which variable is bigger (those are all integers):

```
<?php 
$ectoA=3;
$ectoB=5;
$mesoA=0;
$mesoB=4;
$endoA=11;
$endoB=11;

echo max($ectoA,$ectoB,$mesoA,$mesoB,$endoA,$endoB);
```

I tried with max but it gives the value and not the $varName.

I want to get the name of the variable and if there are two that are equal I need both.

Thanks for the help.

---

As suggested I tried this and worked but still got to know if I have two MAX values I need to do something else...

```
  $confronto = [
    'ectoA' => $ectoA,
    'ectoB' => $ectoB,
    'endoA' => $endoA,
    'endoB' => $endoB,
    'mesoA' => $mesoA,
    'mesoB' => $mesoB,
];

$result= array_keys($confronto,max($confronto));


$neurotipo = $result[0];
echo $neurotipo;
```

I want endoA and endoB to be identified...

Comment: Use an array instead of a bunch of separate variables. There will be multiple advantages to this, including being able to easily find the key that has the largest value.

Comment: It won't give you the variable it'll give you the max as it's value. Don't think of it as a name, think of it as echoing what is inside that variable

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an array instead, or compact your variables into an array:

```
//$array = array('ectoA'=>3,'ectoB'=>5,'mesoA'=>0,'mesoB'=>4,'endoA'=>11,'endoB'=>11);

$array   = compact('ectoA','ectoB','mesoA','mesoB','endoA','endoB');

$result  = array_keys($array, max($array));
```

Then compute the `max()` of that array and use `array_keys()` to search for the max number and return the keys.

```
print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => endoA
    [1] => endoB
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend using an array.  Then you can do something like this:

```
$my_array = array(3, 5, 0, 4, 11, 11);

$maxIndex = 0;    

for($i = 1; $i < count($my_array); $i++) {
    if($my_array[$i] > $my_array[$maxIndex])
        $maxIndex = $i;
}
```

Another option with array keys would be:

```
$my_array = array("ectoA" => 3, "ectoB" => 5, "mesoA" => 0, "mesoB" => 4, "endoA" => 11, "endoB" => 11);

$maxIndex = "ectoA";

while($c = current($my_array)) {
    $key = key($my_array);
    if($my_array[$key] > $my_array[$maxIndex])
        $maxIndex = $key;

    next($my_array);
}
```

Note: Code not tested, but should be the gist of what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

use the array like this

`<?php
    $value= array (
    "ectoA" =>3,
    "ectoB"=>5,
    "mesoA"=>0,
    "mesoB"=>4,
    "endoA"=>11,
    "endoB"=>11);


    $result= array_keys($value,max($values))
    print_r($result);

?>`

Answer (score -2):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php),  **Since the two values are equal, the order they are provided determines the result** $endoA is the biggest here.

But I am not sure your intention is to find the biggest value or which variable is the highest

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems to be a working one.

But it would print for you the value of the maximum number, not the name of the variable.

To have the name of the variable at the end you should add some additional code like:

```
$max = (max($ectoA,$ectoB,$mesoA,$mesoB,$endoA,$endoB);
if($max == $ectoA) echo "ectoA";
if($max == $ectoB) echo "ectoB";
// ... same goes for other variables
```

But working with an array would be the most proper solution.

Comment: sorry but you coder are mory, again sory for my English